# Detect and print the multiples of a specific integer in Perl

Tags: perl, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to write a script that will detect the multiples of an integer that a user entered and is in the range of 200-100. I think I am missing something in my if statement because its not detecting any results for me.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter an integer: ";

my $integer = <STDIN>;

chomp $integer;

my @nums = ( 200 .. 100 );

my $i = 200;

while ( $i < $#nums ) {
    print "$nums[$i]  ";
    ++$i;
}

if ( $i % $integer == 0 ) {
    print "$i\n";
}
```

Comment: ... it's not inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here

- The line

  ```
  my @nums = ( 200 .. 100 )
  ```

  will leave `@nums` empty, because the upper bound of the range is less than the lower bound. You probably want `100 .. 200`
- The variable `$i` starts at 200 and increases, but there are only 101 elements in the array `@nums` (if you reverse the upper and lower bounds). So the value at index 200 is `undef`
- You are printing out *every* value of `$i` within the `while` loop, and then make a single check for divisibility of the value of `$i` after the loop. Presumably you want to test each value inside the loop

I think you meant something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter an integer: ";

my $integer = <STDIN>;
chomp $integer;

for my $n ( 100 .. 200 ) {
    print "$n " if $n % $integer == 0;
}

print "\n";
```

#### output

```
Enter an integer: 7
105 112 119 126 133 140 147 154 161 168 175 182 189 196
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @borodin ..I actually am required to use a while loop instead of for loop for this specific script.

Answer (score 0):

As from you comment.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter an integer: ";
chomp(my $integer = <STDIN>);

my @nums = ( 100 .. 200 );

my $i = 0;

while ( $i < $#nums ) 
{
    print "$nums[$i]  ",if($nums[$i] % $integer == 0);
    $i++;
}
```